# Z-Index not working in multi column menu with React-Router

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a multi-tier, multi-column menu that has been built using https://github.com/kontentino/react-multilevel-dropdown.  The problem I am having is that the submenu items keep appearing underneath the main items.  I have tried multiple attempts using z-index but nothing seems to be helping.

I am including my menu component, my CSS for this page as well as an image of the problem.

If possible I want to avoid trying to roll a custom menu using lists, but am willing to entertain another multi-level menu package.

**MenuBarComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { CurrentPage_Update } from '../../redux/ActionCreators';
import Dropdown from 'react-multilevel-dropdown';

import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
import '../../shared/styles/menu.css'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        siteMap: state.siteMap
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        // CurrentPage_Update: (page) => { dispatch(CurrentPage_Update(page)) }
    }
}

class MenuBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            openCount: 1,
            isOpen: false
        }
    }

    drawLink = (item) => {
        return (
            <NavLink
                to={'/page_' + item.pageId}
                className={`menu menu-link`}
                key={"DDNavLink_" + item.pageId}
                onClick={() => this.setState({ openCount: -1 })}
            >{item.title}</NavLink>

        );
    }

    NavListItem = (item, level, roles) => {


    }

    dropdownItem = (item, level, roles) => {
        let brk = true;
        //TODO: remove next line for production
        item.roles = "*," + item.roles; //Make sure page is shown in development
        if ((item.roles.indexOf("*") < 0) && (item.roles.indexOf("*") < 0)) {
            var itemRoles = item.roles.toLowerCase().split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < itemRoles.length; i++) {
                if (roles.indexOf(itemRoles[i]) > -1) {
                    //if found
                    brk = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (brk) return;
        }

        if (item.children.length > 0) {
            //if any visible children show dropdown
            //only endpoints are clickable
            if (item.children.find((child) => { return child.visible !== "false" })) {
                return (
                    <Dropdown.Item key={'Dropdown_' + item.pageId} className={`menu menu-item-container`}>
                        AA{item.title}
                        <Dropdown.Submenu position='right' className={`menu-UncontrolledDropdown sub${level + 1}`} >
                            {item.children.map((listItem) => {
                                return (this.dropdownItem(listItem, level + 1, roles))
                            })
                            }
                        </Dropdown.Submenu>
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                )
            }
            else { //otherwise if no visible children show only the item
                if (item.visible !== "false") {
                    return (
                        <Dropdown className={`sub${level + 1} menu menu-item-container`
                        } key={"DDItem_" + item.pageId} >
                            BB{level} { this.drawLink(item)}
                        </Dropdown >
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        else { //if no children show only item
            return (
                <Dropdown.Item className={`sub${level} menu menu-item-container`} key={"DDItem" + item.pageId}>
                    CC{level}
                    {this.drawLink(item, level)}
                </Dropdown.Item>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {

        // const setIsOpen = (value) => { this.setState({ isOpen: value }) }
        // const toggle = () => { setIsOpen(!this.state.isOpen) };


        if (this.props.siteMap.errMess) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.siteMap.errMess}
                </div>
            )
        }
        else if (this.props.siteMap.isLoading) {
            return <Loading title="Site Menu" />
        }
        else {
            var roles = this.props.siteMap.siteMapData.userRoles.toLowerCase();
            var siteMap = this.props.siteMap.siteMapData.siteMap;

            return (
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col className="col-2 p-3 menu">
                            <NavLink to='/'>
                                <div className="align-top met-logo"></div>
                            </NavLink>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={{ span: 9, offset: 1 }} className=" menu ">

                            {
                                siteMap.map((link, index) => {
                                    return <div
                                        key={index}
                                        className='p-1 column menu menu-item-container menu-head'>
                                        {this.dropdownItem(link, 0, roles)}
                                    </div>
                                })
                            }



                            {/* https://github.com/kontentino/react-multilevel-dropdown#readme */}


                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MenuBar);
```

---

**menu.css**

```
/*Necessary to force dropdown items into a straight line */

nav>ul>li>a+div>ul>li>a {
  text-indent: 15px;
  /* Can use padding-left as well */
}

.met-logo {
  background-image: url('../images/METLogo.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* width: 128px;
    height: 91px; */
  width: 100px;
  height: 65px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  top: -5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.menu {
  color: #000;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
  /* z-index: 1000000; */
  /* border:solid 1px black; */
}

.menu-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

.menu-dropdown-toggle {
  color: #000;
}

.menu-item-container {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 1px #555;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.menu-item-container :hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.menu-link {
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-bar {
  color: #000;
}

/* .menu-toggler {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
} */

.menu-dropdown-container {
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: wrap;
}

.menu-dropdown-container ul {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: wrap;
}

.menu-link {
  color: #000;
}

.menu-dropdown-title {
  color: #000;
}

.menu-dropdown-body {
  color: #000;
}

.menu-head {
  z-index: 9000!important;
}

.menu-UncontrolledDropdown {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff!important;
  border: solid 1px #555;
  transform: translate(-10%, 15px);
  /* z-index: 99999!important; */
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.sub0 {
  z-index: 12000;
}

.sub1 {
  z-index: 13000;
}

.sub2 {
  z-index: 14000;
}

.sub3 {
  z-index: 15000;
}

.sub4 {
  z-index: 16000;
}

.menu-UncontrolledDropdown :hover {
  background-color: #bbf;
}

.menu-UncontrolledDropdown>div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* .fullWidth {
  width: 100vw!important;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px; 
}*/

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  font: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

**----------**

And here is the example of what the problem is.

[image: Issue example]

I am not using JQuery in this project but React-Bootstrap is used.

Comment: **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).

Comment: Looking at the image you can see that every one of these elements is positioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the code I finally removed all positioning and z-index from my CSS sheet, leaving in the translates for correct positioning.  Leaving the implementation to the component code rather than my own has solved the problems including overlay on the menu column next to the dropdown.